# Plotting non uint8 images with matplotlib

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

I was studying about Python Numpy tutorial from [link](http://cs231n.github.io/python-numpy-tutorial/) when I came across the fact that [matplotlib.pyplot](http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.imshow) was giving strange results when I tried to display some image.

Here's my sample code which I modified from the tutorial link.

```
from scipy.misc import imread, imresize
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

img = imread('cat.jpg')
img_tinted = img * [1, 1, 1]

print img_tinted
# Show the original image
plt.subplot(1, 2, 1)
plt.imshow(img)

# Show the tinted image
plt.subplot(1, 2, 2)

plt.imshow(img_tinted)
plt.show()
```

The output was as follows

```
[[[132 128 117]
  [155 151 139]
  [181 175 161]
  ..., 
  [ 78  68  43]
  [ 76  65  43]
  [ 64  53  31]]]
```

[image]

Even though the data looks to be in the **uint8** format the output image was a strange one. 
**Is there a way to display it similar to the original image?**

Answer (score 1):

A simple solution to this could be to *explicitly typecast unit8* to the image while plotting it with [matplotlib.pyplot](http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.imshow)

Just replacing this code `plt.imshow(img_tinted)` with `plt.imshow(np.uint8(img_tinted))` resolved the issue.

Here's the sample output
[image]

You can even play further with the images

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.misc import imread, imresize
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

img = imread('cat.jpg')
img_tinted = img * [1, 0.5, 0.5]

print np.uint8(img_tinted)

# Show the original image
plt.subplot(1, 3, 1)
plt.imshow(img)

# Show the tinted image
plt.subplot(1, 3, 2)
plt.imshow(np.uint8(img_tinted))

# Show the tinted image without using np.uint8
plt.subplot(1, 3, 3)
plt.imshow(img_tinted)

plt.show()
```

The output was as follows

```
 [[[132 128 117]
  [155 151 139]
  [181 175 161]
  ..., 
  [ 78  68  43]
  [ 76  65  43]
  [ 64  53  31]]]
```

[image]